# how to set conditions in a complex type present in xsd

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xsd

I have a xml schema like shown below.Here i want to achieve two conditions in complex type as shown below

1. Either `ParcelNumber` or `Coordinates` should be present
2. If `WorkArea` is present then `Coordinates` should be mandatory

How to achieve these two conditions in following schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

                                    <xs:sequence>
                                      <xs:element name="WorkLocationCommunityName" type="xs:string" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                  </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>

                </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. XSD 1.0 cannot represent this constraint; XSD 1.1 can using assertions.

   If you mean either or both (regular OR):

   ```
   <xs:assert test="ParcelNumber or WorkArea/WorkLocationCoordinates"/>
   ```

   If you mean either but not both (exclusive OR):

   ```
   <xs:assert test="    (ParcelNumber and not(WorkArea/WorkLocationCoordinates)) 
                     or (not(ParcelNumber) and WorkArea/WorkLocationCoordinates)"/>
   ```

   Place the appropriate assertion after the closing `xs:sequence` tag but still within the `xs:complexType` of the element whose content is being constrained (`WorkLocation`, in this case).
2. Your XSD already represents this because `Coordinates` has a default `minOccurs` of `1` and is a child of `WorkArea`, so when `WorkArea` exists, then `Coordinates` will be required.    [Note that you have two levels of `WorkArea` -- looks like a mistake.]

Comment: In fact I do not know whether you're using XSD 1.0 or 1.1 because you've not said.   My answer is meant to help you understand what is possible in either version.   The constructs supported vary -- in particular `xs:assert` requires XSD 1.1.   To use XSD 1.1, your processor has to support it, and, depending on which processor you're using, you may have to explicitly configure it to use XSD 1.1.

Comment: Automatic generation of an XSD can be useful to get started, but it has inherent limitations in expressing the complete set of constraints you might wish to impose on XML instances other than the instance used to generate the XSD.   Also note that I was referring not to the tool you used to *generate* the XSD but to the tool you used to *validate* XML documents using the XSD.  This validating XML parser has to support the version of XSD needed by the used constructs (ie `xs:assert` requires XSD 1.1).

Comment: I already said where to place the assertion: *Place the appropriate assertion after the closing `xs:sequence` tag but still within the xs:complexType of the element whose content is being constrained (WorkLocation, in this case).*   Again, however, you won't be able to use XSD 1.1 unless your processor supports it, and you've not said what processor you're using to validate XML.  Microsoft products do not support XSD 1.1;  Xerces, Saxon, Altova, etc do.

Comment: You appear to have more fundamental issues than can be addressed inside the scope of a single question.   You might want to break your issues up into multiple other questions.    I hope I've helped provide valuable information to you here and I wish you luck with your project.